# Swiper carousel prev/next to skip more than 1 slide

Tags: jquery, carousel, swiper.js

I am using the Swiper jquery plugin for a logo carousel on a site. The carousel has 10 slides in view and when I click next or previous buttons I would like it to skip another 10 (or whatever I set) slides.

From looking through the API I couldn't see it being possible. If anyone has any ideas...
http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WCMFXBKLRoM

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for an answer on this, then simply use:

```
slidesPerGroup: 10, // 10 being the amount of slides you want to skip.
```

Comment: lol! Why is this so hard to find in the documentation? I just spent like 40 minutes looking.